# How can i identify particular selenium browsers in jasmine when using multiCapabilities?

Tags: selenium, jasmine

I'm currently on a e2e project that tests a website that requires login.
I want to test several browsers and viewpoints.

What is the right way to identify a unique browser?

I am able to identify browsers using the browsername and resolution (only chrome).

```
import { browser } from 'protractor';

 export const userCredentials = {
    'chrome-1350' : {
        'email' : 'piet@example.com',
        'password' : '#######'
    },
    'chrome-1000' : {
      'email' : 'jan@example.com',
      'password' : '#######'
    },
    'chrome-550' : {
        'email' : 'laura@example.com',
        'password' : '#######'
      },
    'firefox' : {
        'email' : 'astrid@example.com',
        'password' : '#######'
      }
};

export class Users {

  public static async getEmail(): Promise<string> {
    const cap = await browser.getCapabilities();
    let browserName = await cap.get('browserName');
      if (browserName === 'chrome') {
          await browser.driver.manage().window().getSize().then(function(size) {
          browserName =  'chrome-' + size.width;
        });
      }
      return userCredentials[browserName].email;
  }

  public static async getPassword(): Promise<string> {
    const cap = await browser.getCapabilities();
    let browserName = await cap.get('browserName');
    if (browserName === 'chrome') {
      await browser.driver.manage().window().getSize().then(function (size) {
        browserName = 'chrome-' + size.width;
      });
    }
    return userCredentials[browserName].password;
  }
}
```